# How to consisely replace a value inside Option?

Tags: scala, functor, option-type

I want to replace a value inside an `Option` iff it is non-empty. I can do it using a constant function using `map(_ => newValue)` like in

```
Some("text").map(_ => 42)
```

Is there a more concise way, like Haskell's [`<$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor.html#v%3a-60--36-) in `42 <$ Just "text"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet):

```
scala> 1.some >| "x"
res0: Option[String] = Some(x)

scala> none[Int] >| "x"
res1: Option[String] = None
```

You could use `as` instead of `>|`.

If you are looking for something "like in Haskell" you probably should take a look at `Scalaz`.

Answer (score 8):

IMO that's pretty concise already. It doesn't get any shorter than that with the standard library. (See below for an answer using Scalaz.)